# Lexical or Preprocesssor issue in xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5, zip, unzip

i'm working on one zip and unzip module, i have uploaded all files into my folder,
but its still showing that

```
#include "minizip/zip.h"
#include "minizip/unzip.h"
```

These files are missing... with the error Lexical or Preprocesssor issue..
Can any one please help in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the `minizip` directory added to your project hierarchy. The easiest way is to just drag the `minizip` folder from the Finder to your project window.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the header path to: **"User Header Search Paths"** to search your headers in Build Settings?